# What is a good approximation of $(1-p)(1-q)$ as $(1-x)^2$, for $p,q \in (0,1)$?

Tags: probability, approximation, mathematical-modeling

I'm doing some scientific modeling, and I want to use $(1-x)^2$ to approximate $(1-p)(1-q)$, with $p, q \in (0,1)$. $p$ and $q$ are probabilities, and are not near zero.  My intuition is that since I'm approximating a product, the geometric mean $x=\sqrt{pq}$ is a good choice--better, at least, than the average $\frac{pq}{2}$.  Does this seem sensible?  Are there other recommendations you'd suggest considering?  (Is the question too vague?)

Comment: You might as well be approximating $pq$ by $x^{2}$ for $x,p,q \in (0,1)$. It is an equivalent problem under the change of variable $y \to 1-y.$ The exact answer to that question is $x = \sqrt{pq}.$ Therefore the exact answer to the original problem is $x = 1 - \sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}$. Check it out: you get $(1-x)^{2} = (1-p)(1-q).$

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  I didn't see that.  It's obvious now--enough that I'm embarrased.  (Why not post it as an answer @GeoffRobinson?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exact solution: $x = 1 - \sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}$.